# Jupyter file open doesn't appear in the new file list

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I fell like I'm might be doing something really silly here but I've been researching for 30 mins and can't find an answer.

I'm working in Pycharm on python version 3.7. In pycharm I have created a new project and within have set a venv with python 3.7 as the interpreter. I then went to settings and installed the jupyter meta package version 1.0.0. I got the message "Package 'jupyter' installed successfully."

When I go to create a new file however I don't have the option to create a jupyter file, only a .py file.

I've tried restarting my computer (I'm on a mac) and I have tried setting up the project in a conda environment, neither made any difference. I also thought am I actually installing jupyter-notebook so I then installed jupyterlab 1.2.4  and I still can't create a jupyter-notebook file.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the professional version of PyCharm supports Jupyter notebooks.

Here is a full tutorial on how to configure PyCharm to use Jupyter notebooks:

- [Jupyter notebook support in PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html)

Comment: Okay thanks, that was the guidance I was following but I didn’t realise I would need professional pycharm